# React JS: setState is late on last input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm sorry, if I can't explain my problem properly because english is not my
main language.

I create a form component (written in es6) something like this:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(args);
    this.state = { input: '' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
         <input
           type="text"
           onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)}
         />
      </form>
    );
  }

  onInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
    console.log(`state: ${this.state}, value: ${e.target.value}`); // this is my checking
  }
}
```

You see the line where I do `console.log`? Now, when I try to type something
on the browser:

```
// I type this: my word
// on every character input, the output is:

// state: , value: m
// state: m, value: my
// state: my, value: my 
// state: my , value: my w
// state: my w, value: my wo
// state: my wo, value: my wor
// state: my wor, value: my word

// I do backspace
// state: my word, value: my wor
// state: my wor, value: my wo
// state: my wo, value: my w
// state: my w, value: my 
// state: my , value: my
// state: my, value: m
// state: m, value:
```

See? The state is late one character on each input. This is not good for
validating the input length. What did I do wrong there? Or, did I miss
something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use a callback on the `setState` method.

```
onInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value }, () => {
        console.log(`state: ${this.state}, value: ${e.target.value}`);
    });
}
```

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate):

> The second (optional) parameter is a callback function that will be
>   executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.

Comment: Waw, I miss that important thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) does not immediately mutate `this.state`., you can pass to [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) callback as a second argument and get updated state

```
onInputChange(e) {
  this.setState({ input: e.target.value }, () => {
    console.log(`state: ${this.state}, value: ${e.target.value}`); // this is my checking
  });
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/28673/)

Answer (score 1):

This happened because console.log started even before this.setState completed its action. You need to pass the console.log in a callback to ensure that this is called only after this.setState completes.

```
onInputChange(e) {
   this.setState({ input: e.target.value }, () => {
     console.log(`state: ${this.state}, value: ${e.target.value}`); // the console message code
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the changed value immediately after updating then you can use another auxiliary variable.

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(args);
    this.state = { input: '' };
    this.input = "";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
         <input
           type="text"
           onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)}
         />
      </form>
    );
  }

  onInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
    this.input = e.target.value;
    console.log(`state: ${this.input}, value: ${e.target.value}`); // this is my checking
  }
}
```

But you should you this.state.text variable to show values on UI.